# user on an editing spree

Tags: feature-request, editing, bumping

One of us has edited over 50 old questions in the last 50 minutes, mostly just retagging them. Is there any way to stop this? [note --- I have flagged one of the questions for moderator attention, and I have left a comment or two asking this over-zealous editor to stop; I guess what I'm asking is whether the software can be trained to lock out people on editing sprees]

Comment: I've posted [a similar feature request on Meta.SO a while ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137831/warn-or-block-users-from-flooding-the-front-page-with-edits)

Comment: Yes, please stop. It is fine to strive for edit related or taxonomy badge, but not in this way, because you are monopolizing the front page.  Martin might be able to give some guidelines/advice, as he once carried out a formidable retagging job (getting rid of a deprecated tag). How many did you do at a time? 6 or 8? It was noticable to me, because we live on (more or less) the same time zone. I'm sad to say I was mildly annoyed by even his lower volume retagging until I learned the true purpose behind it :-)

Comment: Somewhat related: [How much bumping is too much?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5068/) Of course, even if someone retags slowly, it still annoys people following related tags. @Jyrki I started fast and someone told me not to do that. I continued at about 20 questions a week, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms/2434#comment12140_2434). Other users were removing the algebra tag, too; so it went faster than that. [700 questions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740?m=5031497#5031497) were removed in 3 months.

Comment: Those young kids, I think we need to up the unsupervised editing (and retagging) privileges to 10k :-)

Comment: My solution, which would not have been likely to help most new or unregistered users, was to temporarily add the tag in question to my "ignored tags" list.

Comment: Gerry, I would like to add on your request and whenever an edit is suggested/done to a post older than (say) six months a warning will appear pointing out that fact to the user.

Comment: I'm guilty of this. I was unaware that these small edits re-activate the question. Hopefully there's a way to remedy this.

Comment: It begs the question *why* edited posts get bumped to the front page. I can see why bumping happens for user self-editing (improving?) her own question, or if a new answer gets posted (maybe even a comment, which could arguably provide new insight). The only reason to bump edits I can see is to allow others to check, and ensure that no vandalism occurs, for which frontline bumping strikes me as not a good solution.

Comment: Reputation cutoff as suggested in a comment by @AsafKaragilia might be a solution, but as is, it prevents and shuts down any well-intended desire to improve layout etc of old posts; and why should that be the case for answers providing a repository for searches?

Comment: @gnometorule As you are a member of a community which takes logic very seriously, I highly encourage you to read about what [begging the question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begs_the_question) means (or is supposed to mean) before you use it again. This is just informational, so I hope I don't bug you.

Comment: @rschwieb: Thanks for pointing out an expression I apparently have misused in the past, and here (not on par with, way back, sharing that Germans bbq "Mais" (pronounced, and taken as "mice"), as opposed to "corn")! I appreciate. I meant to say it "raises the question," and ask it to be read that way as I cannot edit an old comment.

Comment: @gnometorule I'm glad it was useful for you :) Now when we are advanced to old age, you can join me in railing against the butchering of precise language :/

Comment: @rschwieb: Count me in! (see also 3 (b) of my answer to "How "civil" should we be :) ) That said, I *have* reached what I consider old age, or at least am frighteningly close to it. :)